# Erro charset Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Criei o database no Firebase e adicionei alguns registros, porém está dando erro em relação as palavras com caracteres especiais no Recyclerview do Android e também no próprio site do Firebase. A palavra no exemplo é Recepção.

No Firebase

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No Recyclerview

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu estava importando os dados do Sublime para o Firebase. Salvei os arquivos do Sublime Text e coloquei em UTF-8. Com isso os caracteres funcionou no Firebase.